# I have a hard time finding how to display a python code in html

Tags: python, html, flask, web-scraping

**Hi, I'm Currently programming a website for displaying all the previous year questions of a competitive exam in India name JEE. For getting the Questions and their Respective Options I used bs4 and requests to web scrape from a website named ExamSide where all these questions and options are available it was successful while printing it in Python Prompt(i have given the code below) but I have hard time finding how to display this stuffs in my html page via django or flask**

*It would be Really Helpful If you Guys Help me Out*
*Thanks in Advance*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
webpage_codes = ['lgnz9975', 'lgnzeywd', 'lgnzj56q', 'lgnzt580', 'lgnw7ha3', 'lgnwmpwc','lgnx2ht3', 'lgnx23k6', 'lgny1m5w', 'lgny7rsq']
i = 0
hello = 1
print("JEE MAINS 15th Morning Session")
print("Difficulty : Medium")
while i < len(webpage_codes):
    r = requests.get("https://questions.examside.com/past-years/year-wise/jee/jee-main/jee-main-2023-online-15th-april-morning-shift/"+webpage_codes[i])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    questions = []
    options = []
    s = soup.find('div', class_ = "flex-grow flex flex-col gap-2 lg:gap-4")
    result_set = s.find_all('div')
    for h in result_set:
        if h.get('class') == ['question', 'xl:text-lg', 'px-4', 'py-2.5']:
            questions += [h.text]
    for a in result_set:
        if a.get('class') == ['grow', 'question', 'xl:text-lg']:
            options += [a.text]
    for z in range(0, len(options)):
        options[z] = options[z].replace("$", "$$")
    
    for y in range(0, len(questions)):
        questions[y] = questions[y].replace("$", "$$")
    w = 0
    for c in questions:
        if options[w] == '':
            pass
        else:
            print(str(hello)+".", end = "")
            print(c)
            print("A.",options[w])
            w += 1
            print("B.",options[w])
            w += 1
            print("C.",options[w])
            w += 1
            print("D.",options[w])
            w += 1
            print("\n\n")
            hello += 1
    i = i+ 1
```

Comment: You seem to ask how to work with Django or Flask. There is documentation for Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/#first-steps) and Flask (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/) available. The topic is far to broad to cover it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, can you try it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import render

def display_questions(request):
    webpage_codes = ['lgnz9975', 'lgnzeywd', 'lgnzj56q', 'lgnzt580', 'lgnw7ha3', 'lgnwmpwc','lgnx2ht3', 'lgnx23k6', 'lgny1m5w', 'lgny7rsq']
    i = 0
    hello = 1
    data = []
    while i < len(webpage_codes):
        r = requests.get("https://questions.examside.com/past-years/year-wise/jee/jee-main/jee-main-2023-online-15th-april-morning-shift/"+webpage_codes[i])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        questions = []
        options = []
        s = soup.find('div', class_ = "flex-grow flex flex-col gap-2 lg:gap-4")
        result_set = s.find_all('div')
        for h in result_set:
            if h.get('class') == ['question', 'xl:text-lg', 'px-4', 'py-2.5']:
                questions += [h.text]
        for a in result_set:
            if a.get('class') == ['grow', 'question', 'xl:text-lg']:
                options += [a.text]
        for z in range(0, len(options)):
            options[z] = options[z].replace("$", "$$")
        for y in range(0, len(questions)):
            questions[y] = questions[y].replace("$", "$$")
        w = 0
        for c in questions:
            if options[w] == '':
                pass
            else:
                question_data = {
                    'number': hello,
                    'question': c,
                    'option_a': options[w],
                    'option_b': options[w+1],
                    'option_c': options[w+2],
                    'option_d': options[w+3],
                }
                data.append(question_data)
                w += 4
                hello += 1
        i = i + 1
    
    return render(request, 'questions.html', {'data': data})
```

And the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JEE Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JEE Questions</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Option A</th>
            <th>Option B</th>
            <th>Option C</th>
            <th>Option D</th>
        </tr>
        {% for question in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ question.number }}</td>
            <td>{{ question.question }}</td>
            <td>{{ question.option_a }}</td>
            <td>{{ question.option_b }}</td>
            <td>{{ question.option_c }}</td>
            <td>{{ question.option_d }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to align the maths equation?